# error: ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID con fetch() en web

Tags: javascript, api, .net, fetch, ssl

estoy haciendo una web en .net y necesito llamar a una api, la api tiene https y demás pero al llamarla me retorna el siguiente error:

```
ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

mi código para llamarla desde javascript es el siguiente:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            const tokenUsuario = $('.tokenUsuario').text();
           

            (async () => {
                const rawResponse = await fetch('https://rutaApi/api/metodo', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        "Content-Type": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        'token': tokenUsuario
                    }, 
                });
                const content = await rawResponse.json();

                console.log(content);
            })();

        });
```

desde el postman me funciona, pero tuve que darle a algo de desactivar verificación ssl para que me funcionase en el postman, alguien sabe como puedo hacer para que me funcione en mi web? Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Tienes un certificado autofirmado? Esa podría ser la causa. Intenta instalar un certificado gratuito de [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/es/).

Comment: tengo uno autofirmado, pero no se como solucionar el error.

Comment: y porqué puede dar problemas un certificado autofirmado???

Comment: El certificado autofirmado no está validado por una entidad reconocida y, por tanto, no se puede verificar, de ahí el error `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`. Tal vez te sirva leer [este artículo](https://kinsta.com/es/base-de-conocimiento/neterr-cert-authority-invalid/).